# ModX - How to edit logo being displayed?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I've got a multilanguage ModX site. And noticed that when changing languages, it displays a different logo. WHat I need to do is to setup same logo for both languages. Basically:

English side showing: logo.png

Other language side showing: logo-new.png

I don't want to replace logo-new.png file with the correct image file on server in case another part of the site uses that file. So I'm left with actually editing the site header to show the correct logo.

When I go to ModX's site template, I see this code for the header:

```
<img src="[[++site_logo_img]]" itemprop="logo" class="site-logo">
```

So my question would be, where do I go to edit the ++site_logo_img value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web context try to look in system settings, for other contexts in context settings - https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/contexts

Answer (score 1):

```
[[++site_logo_img]]
```

This is a MODX setting, these can be found in settings or in context settings.

Lets say you need a different logo for 2 MODX contexts, you can set a **site_logo_img** different setting in each context.